# What is the cheapest way to get from Weeze Airport to Amsterdam?

Tags: budget, transportation, amsterdam, dusseldorf, rotterdam

I am gonna land at Weeze airport on November 21 at about 12:00. I will have 4 days for traveling. I would like to go to Amsterdam and I am looking for the cheapest way to do so.

I am planning to spend two days there and after go to Rotterdam for one day. On the last day, I want to go to Dusseldorf and the next morning I will have a flight back from Weeze.

Could you give me some hints on how to travel between these cities in a cheap way? Or tell is this a good option or should I go to some of these cities Dusseldorf, Duisburg, Cologne, and Essen instead.

Comment: Please don't edit in new questions to the original, especially after answers have been given for the original.

Answer (score 9):

The cheapest from Weeze to Amsterdam (using public transport) is to walk across the border from Weeze and catch a bus on the Dutch side to the nearest train station. It might even be the fastest, too.

The connection from The Netherlands to Weeze (and back) is not quite convenient. You should at least consider visiting towns on the German side of the border.

Comment: There is a bus stop at the Kasteellaan in Well, here: https://goo.gl/maps/GzsKRuhhiQHLtq9E7 . It's a 6.5km walk from Weeze airport.

Comment: For convenience, I wonder if a taxi might be possible to the closest Netherlands bus stop :D

Comment: @Jan but be prepared for a bit of a premium due to a destination outside the working area of the taxi.

Comment: I actually looked into this a few years ago. I think I remember that the shortest walking route involves a path that's not accessible to cars. But, I might misremember, and this might have changed.

Answer (score 7):

So the two (cheap) transport options seem to be to walk either to a Dutch bus stop or to Weeze train station:

[image: map showing routes to Weeze and Dutch bus stop]

## Weeze train station

Tickets from the train station to Amsterdam typically seem to cost around 40 euros, but sometimes are available for 25 euros if you book early and are lucky timewise. Tickets can be booked on bahn.de. As far as I can tell there is currently a train replacement bus leaving from the train station, but I believe this temporary.

## Dutch bus stop

### Prices

From the Dutch bus stop (Bushalte Kasteellaan, Well L) you can either take a bus to Venray with Arriva or to Nijmegen with Breng costing 2.83 and 8.12 respectively. Note that without a Dutch OV chipkaart this price *might* be higher (unless you figure out a way to buy the ticket digitally, Breng works with the Tranzer app and Arriva with the Glimble app, but I didn't check prices in there).

From Venray the normal train price to Amsterdam is 24.89 . If you buy at the train station it's one euro extra, but you can use the NS app instead. If however you buy through Gaiyo and you travel outside rush hour (The off-peak hours are on weekdays from 00:00 - 06:30, between 09:00 - 16:00 and between 18:30 - 24:00 the next morning, plus all day at weekends) it's 10% off for 22.40, for a total of 25.23 euros.

From Nijmegen the normal train price to Amsterdam is 20.70. With the 10% off that works out to a total (including bus) of 26.75.

But: There are often (not right now) better discounts available for Dutch trains which are often fixed price regardless of the distance, which can always be found on treinreiziger.nl (use Google Translate).

### Times

Times when the best connections happen can be found on 9292.nl from "Bushalte Kasteellaan, Well L" to "Amsterdam Centraal". Travel time is 2.5 to 3 hours.

## My recommendation

Take the German connection if it is available for the 25 euros, especially if it's fully by train. Otherwise check treinreiziger.nl and 9292.nl for the best connection.

Answer (score 5):

Weeze Airport is poorly connected to public transportation and often the savings by flying Ryan Air are easily eaten up by transport from/to the airport. Take a look at  https://www.weeze.de/de/inhalt/oeffentlicher-personennahverkehr/ Note that the  busses don't run at night and even during the day it's once an hour at best.

"Best" options often depends on the specific time of day and it what trade offs in convenience you are willing to make. "Cheapest" is clearly walking: it's free. It takes about 13 hours to Düsseldorf and 30 hours to Amsterdam.

You can look at train tickets for your specific times to both locations at [www.bahn.de](http://www.bahn.de) . Weeze airport to Amsterdam will run you around 25 Euros and takes about 3 and a half hours to 4 hours. These will include a lot of changes.

Comment: I'm half-surprised it's not called Amsterdam/Düsseldorf Airport (Weeze), in the best tradition of the (bankrupt) Frankfurt Hahn or Stockholm Skavsta.

Comment: Ryan Air calls  it  indeed "Düsseldorf Weeze".

Comment: Wasn't there a court case that forbade the airport using 'Düsseldorf Weeze' due to the distance between the two? @gerrit

Comment: @gerrit the Amsterdam airport is technically not in Amsterdam LOL It is in Schiphol which is part of gemeente Haarlemmermeer. But at least the train connection is decent

Comment: @JulianaKarasawaSouza irrelevant. It's far closer to Amsterdam than Weeze is to Dusseldorf. And yes, there was such a court case though I don't know the outcome. It wasn't against the airport but against Ryanair for selling tickets to and from "Dusseldorf" when they were to and from Weeze (which is and was the name of the airport).

Comment: I wonder if walking is cheapest, given the cost of additional food and drink required for a 30 hour walk (with luggage?).

Comment: Even Dortmund airport is closer to Düsseldorf than Weeze, has much better public transport connections, and has plenty of low-cost airlines flying there as well.

Comment: and the new Berlin airport is technically outside Berlin but it's right up against the edge of the city so calling it Berlin is pretty reasonable.

Answer (score 4):

The website https://www.rome2rio.com suggests bus to Weeze train station, train to Kleve, bus to Nijmegen,  and then train to Amsterdam. Travel time 3:36, plus waiting times. From Rotterdam, train to Breda, train to Nijmegen.

If you want to cram in Dusseldorf (I think most people would choose Cologne of the Ruhr cities), I think it would be better to do Rotterdam->Amsterdam-Dusseldorf.

Comment: +1 for recommending Köln over Düsseldorf.

Answer (score 4):

One option that hasn't been mentioned is ridesharing ([blablacar.de](https://www.blablacar.de/)). You have to be quite flexible with time, cannot plan so long in advance, and will probably need a bus or train to get from the airport to some town where someone is able to pick you up so it won't be a great option for such a short trip but it is typically cheaper than busses and quite a bit cheaper than trains.

Answer (score 3):

Check the app "BlaBlaCar", which is basically an app for one-time carpooling. Somebody who goes remotely that direction will make a small detour to pick you up, you participate in gas money and they'll drop you off near your desired area. I just checked, the price for your trip should around 7€. This might be the cheapest option, takes 2 hours, **however** as it's not public transport per se, it's not predictable if someone is actually going this way when you actually need it. Apparently it's not a much offered route, but you could be lucky.

Edit:

I just realized you had multiple questions besides the initial one:
Your trip seems rather confusing and too much for such a short amount of time. No matter what means of transport you use, even if everything seems close, you will be stuck in trains a lot. I'd rather focus on one aspect, either you want to check out Amsterdam and Rotterdam, while skipping Dusseldorf. *Or* you check out the German part of that area and come back for another trip to the Netherlands. Two cities + travel will already be more than enough for 4 days and I'm sure you do not want to only see the central station of Rotterdam and Dusseldorf, but explore a bit. Both are beautiful cities that deserve more than half a day. If it's more of a checklist of places you wanted to be at, or in case you want to sacrifice sleep it's possible, the train only takes 2-3h from Rotterdam to Dusseldorf.

Regarding your last question: I used to live in that area for a few decades and especially in Essen for 7 years (funny, never expected to read that cities' name here). My recommendation is to *not* go there or Duisburg if you don't have specific destinations there! While they can have their own certain vibe, it is not worth to sacrifice your really limited time. Both of these cities are characterized by the glorious days of coal mining and blue collar workers, which resulted in cities that don't have much to offer if you don't know where to look (and what you are looking for). Dusseldorf and Cologne are really friendly to tourists, there is so much going on you're barely able to cover everything major in 2 days + the nightlife is way more inviting, if you plan on going out in the nights. Essen and Duisburg would be way more historic and industrial, rather than fancy, clean cities.

Again, if you already have a certain destination or atmosphere you're looking for - go for it! But if you just considered those cities because they are big: reconsider!

Answer (score 2):

It depends what you want to see and visit, but the cities on the German side are certainly worth a visit. There is a lot of industrial heritage: a mining-museum (more then 1 possibly), railroad-museum, villa Hugel/Krupp museum as well as other historic and big city cultural sights and events.
The Ruhr area has a tourist site:
https://www.ruhr-tourismus.de/en/subjects/culture/museums.html
And of course you can check lonely planet, tripadvisor, and so on. It really depends on what you want to see.

The nice thing about the Ruhr area is that it is all well connected by public traffic. I think you have to decide what you are most interested in, and decide if you want to go either to the Netherlands or to Germany.
Amsterdam and Rotterdam are also well worth a visit and have a good train connection between them.